# Count the number of free tickets for each flight

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables : flights, planes and purchases. The table structure are as follow :

- `flights` :-  flight_id : the unique flight id;
  plane_id :  the id of the plane making the flight.
- `planes` :- plane_id : the unique plane id;
  number_of_seats : the number of seats on the plane.
- `purchases` :- flight_id : the flight id of the purchases;
  seat_no : the seat number of the purchase.

It is guarantee that in the `purchases` table, the pair (flight_id , seat_no) are unique.

Question : I have to calculate number of free tickets per flight_id.

I used the below query. Although it gave me result but didn’t passed the test cases. Can someone please tell me what did I miss. Thanks in advance.

```
with
number_of_ticket as 
  (select f.flight_id , sum(number_of_seats) as total_seats 
   from flights as f join planes as p on p.plane_id = f.plane_id 
   group by f.flight_id),
        
booked_ticket_as 
  (select pr.flight_id , count(seat_no) as booked_seats 
   from purchases 
   group by flight_id)
        
Select booked_ticket_as.flight_id , (number_of_ticket.total_seats - booked_ticket_as.booked_seats) as free_seats 
    from booked_ticket_as 
    join number_of_ticket 
    on number_of_ticket.flight_id = booked_ticket_as.flight_id
```

Comment: Hello! As per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There is some needlessly complicated stuff in your query. Why do you sum over the number of seats in the first query? Each flight has exactly one plane and each plane already has the total amount of seats in the table `planes`.

Comment: @buddemat thanks a lot for your answer.I think I miss read the question and didn’t understood the columns.

Comment: Please define "free ticket".   I would assume that it would be a ticket with a price of zero, but your data doesn't specify any pricing columns.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you provided testdata and the failing testcase but this should work. Your query probably is missing results for flights that haven't sold a single ticket (ie all seats are still available)

```
with ticketcount as 
  (select flight_id, count(seat_no) as seats
   from purchases
   group by flight_id)

select f.flight_id, (p.number_of_seats - coalesce(t.seats, 0)) as free_seats
from flights f inner join planes p on f.plane_id = p.plane_id 
     left join ticketcount t on t.flight_id = f.flight_id
```

- The `with ticketcount` clause calculates the number of sold tickets for each flight.
- As the `planes` table already contains the number of seats per plane, there is no need to group or sum up anything, you can just start joining.
- The `flighs inner join plane` gets the total number of available seats per flight.
- The `left join ticketcount` combines this with the number of sold tickets per flight. I use a `left join` so that also flights without any sold tickets are included in the result.
- The number of `free_seats` is then the difference of `p.number_of_seats - t.seats`. But as for flights, which don't have any tickets sold yet, `t.seats` is `null`, I used `coalesce(t.seats, 0)` which will return the first argument from the argumentslist which is different from `null`

Comment: 'It would be easier if you provided testdata'. Why, when, plainly, there's no incentive?

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for your answer here. I am new to stack-overflow so my way of putting the question might not be optimal. I will try to improve it from next time. Thanks everyone for your answers. This is a great place to learn.

Comment: @anmolkhandelwal If my answer solved your problem, please accept/upvote